# Is there any browser add-on or extension or anything, by which we can see their current page views?

Tags: google, google-search-console, pagerank, browsers, browser-support

Is there any browser add-on or extension or anything, by which we can see their current page views of websites displayed in google search results?

or

give us the page views of websites opened in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Alexa's toolbar](http://www.alexa.com/) shows a ranking that is based on the number of visitors to a site. Though it is not a complete count of every hit a site gets, it is a guide that will tell you who gets more and who gets less traffic.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless a website publicly releases this information there is no way to get that information.

Comment: John, I have seen websiteoutlook.dot.com and other such websites.